# How to setHeight for a ViewGroup

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how can I setHeight for a ViewGroup?
I see there is a layout(l,t,r,b);

But that is different form setHeight(), since I don't know where should be the top/bottom of the viewGroup. I need to set the height of the ViewGroup and return that to ListAdapter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using  `setLayoutParams()`

```
myViewGroup.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) the descriptions of the parameters to LayoutParams

```
public ViewGroup.LayoutParams (int width, int height)    

Creates a new set of layout parameters with the specified width and height.

width the width, either MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT or a fixed size in pixels
height the height, either MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT or a fixed size in pixels
```

Comment: What if my parent height is "wrap_content"? Is there a way to layout my Viewgroup with a specified height?

Comment: LayoutParams accepts FILL_PARENT, CONTENT_WRAP or a fixed size in pixel. So you can try 
myViewGroup.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100,200))